# Javascript: how to get nested JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js

```
{
"category": [
    {
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_name": "Editor's Choice ",
        "cover_url": "http://www.example.com"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "2",
        "category_name": "New Releases",
        "cover_url": "http://www.example.com"
    }
],
"success": 1
```

}

The problem is that i'm scraping with nodejs an html page from my local cinema website, i have 3 arrays (ar1,ar2,ar3) which cointain titles of the film programmed from now to the next three days.

i'm using this way to get the json (this is only for one day), that is the "heart" of the function, where i generate the array that will be strigify then:

```
            var len = titolo1.length;
            while(j!=len){
                obj1={titolo:titolo1[j],locandina:film1[j]};
                js[j]=obj1;
                j++;
            }
```

then  in other point of server code (out of function!) i do  res.send(JSON.stringify(js, null, 4))

and this is the result:

```
[
{
    "titolo": " The Gunman ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/RIBqwqVPwUp6VIWeRZlS-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Doraemon il film ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/doraemon-il-film-le-avventure-di-nobita-e-dei-cinque-esploratori_notizia-2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Child 44 – Il bambino numero 44 ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/Child-44-trailer-italiano-e-locandina-del-thriller-con-Gary-Oldman-e-Tom-Hardy-2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Run All Night – Una notte per sopravvivere ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/locandina2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Ritorno al Marigold Hotel ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/36366-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " I 7 nani ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/xHIrTDXTLZF1jBd7CQNf-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Adaline – L’eterna giovinezza ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/adaline-poster-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Avengers: Age of Ultron – 2D ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/ultron.poster-2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Fast and Furious 7 ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/49946-150x214.jpg"
}
```

]

now, i'd like to reach this type of json:

```
{
"day1": [
    {
        "title": "blablablalbal",
    },
    {
        "title": "blablablalbal",
    }
],
"day2": [
    {
        "title": "blablablalbal",
    },
    {
        "title": "blablablalbal",
    }
],
"day3": [
    {
        "title": "blablablalbal",
    },
    {
        "title": "blablablalbal",
    }
]
```

}

how can i do that?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Marco - I understand your English okay. Yet, you need to give an example of the data structure you want.  I think you only need to make a small change to your loop to add the "film" prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco -

If you will always have 3 arrays, the simple answer is:

```
var films = {day1: ar1, day2: ar2, day3: ar3};
res.send(JSON.stringify( films, null, 4 ));
```

You could also write a simple function to join and name the data. Run the example below to test.

If this is not what you want then please provide more information.

**Example:**

```html
<html>
  <body>
<b>Calendario Eventi</b><br>
   <textarea id="stdout" style="width:90%;height:20em;padding:1em;border:1px black solid;background-color:aliceblue;"></textarea>
    


<script type="text/javascript">
  
  function main() {
    var films = joinData([ ar1, ar2, ar3 ]);  
    document.getElementById('stdout').value = JSON.stringify( films, null, '  ' );
  }
  
function joinData( data ) {
  var i, obj={};
  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    obj["day" + (1 + i ) ] = data[i];
  }
  return obj;
}  
  
// EXAMPLE DATA: Films today, tomorrow, ...  

var ar1 = [
{
    "titolo": " Child 44 – Il bambino numero 44 ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/Child-44-trailer-italiano-e-locandina-del-thriller-con-Gary-Oldman-e-Tom-Hardy-2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Run All Night – Una notte per sopravvivere ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/locandina2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Ritorno al Marigold Hotel ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/36366-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " I 7 nani ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/xHIrTDXTLZF1jBd7CQNf-150x214.jpg"
}
];
  
var ar2 = [
{
    "titolo": " I 7 nani ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/xHIrTDXTLZF1jBd7CQNf-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Adaline – L’eterna giovinezza ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/adaline-poster-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Avengers: Age of Ultron – 2D ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/ultron.poster-2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Fast and Furious 7 ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/49946-150x214.jpg"
}
];
    
var ar3 = [
{
    "titolo": " The Gunman ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/RIBqwqVPwUp6VIWeRZlS-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Doraemon il film ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/doraemon-il-film-le-avventure-di-nobita-e-dei-cinque-esploratori_notizia-2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Child 44 – Il bambino numero 44 ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/Child-44-trailer-italiano-e-locandina-del-thriller-con-Gary-Oldman-e-Tom-Hardy-2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Run All Night – Una notte per sopravvivere ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/locandina2-150x214.jpg"
},
{
    "titolo": " Ritorno al Marigold Hotel ",
    "locandina": "http://www.metropoliscinemas.it/wp-content/uploads/36366-150x214.jpg"
}
];
  
  main();
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```